# Uneditable object only visible in object mode

Tags: modeling

I found this uneditable object, it's exactly the same size with my original hood, and I can't do anything with it.
Can anyone tell me how this happened? And what should I do to delete this unnecessary object?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Alt+H (Unhide vertices)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what the problem is from the provided information, but Array Modifier with edit mode visibility turned off would behave exactly like you describe:

[image]

Comment: It used to have subsurf, shrink, mirror modifiers, but I deleted them all just for testing, the uneditable object is still existing.

Comment: Can you [share the file](https://blend-exchange.com/)?